# Qual è il significato di "fare Rugantino" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto:

> Agostino veniva tutti i giorni, no? Veniva con quell'aria, mo' vestito da turco, mo' da cavaliere, la collana in petto. Era bravo a *fare Rugantino*, ci faceva ridere noi ragazzi, che era una degnazione, uno che si teneva omo grande.

Non capisco cosa significa "fare Rugantino" in questo brano. Tenete conto che il personaggio che dice queste parole è la pittrice Artemisia Gentileschi, e lo fa nel seicento, e che l'autrice ha scritto il romanzo tra il 1944 e il 1947. Quindi, non può riferirsi a questa [Commedia musicale](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rugantino_(commedia_musicale)). Sapreste spiegarmi il significato di questa espressione in questo contesto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rugantino è una maschera tradizionale della commedia dell'arte romana, definito come *er bullo de Trastevere, svelto co' le parole e cor cortello*.
Fare Rugantino dunque significa impersonare quella parte, non solo in una rappresentazione teatrale, ma anche in modo giocoso con gli amici.
Dato che la commedia dell'arte era in voga nel XVII secolo in Italia, è ben credibile che nel seicento qualcuno si divertisse a fare Rugantino nelle case degli amici.

Comment: Non ho trovato di meglio, però [wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rugantino_%28maschera%29) fa risalire la nascita di Rugantino come maschera alla fine del 1700.

Comment: In effetti anche l'[enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/rugantino/) menziona un'origine settecentesca. Un piccolo anacronismo della Banti?

Comment: Curioso: prima di fare la domanda, avevo cercato "Rugantino" su Google. Ho trovato molti nomi di ristoranti e alcuni riferimenti alla commedia musicale menzionata nella domanda, ma niente su questa maschera della commedia dell'arte.

Comment: @DaG: veramente strano, dato che Anna Banti era un'esperta critica d'arte.

Comment: @Charo: Non saprei, forse la Banti sapeva o ipotizzava che prima delle prime attestazioni la maschera fosse già diffusa popolarmente. Oltre alla maschera e prima della commedia, il “Rugantino” è anche un'[amata rivista](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rugantino_(periodico)) in romanesco, che ha avuto il suo momento di maggior successo alla fine dell'Ottocento.